# c compiler: arrays as function parameters

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am writing a compiler for a `"c-like"` language. Currently, the compiler supports arrays in local scope. Each element of an array may be accessed using bracket notation---`a[0], a[1],...`. to support this data structure, a symbol table is used to keep track of the symbols in the current scope, and the address of the next available memory space. to demonstrate, consider the following code:

`int a[5]; int b;`

using a stack implementation, and given a 4 byte aligned memory: in order to access, e.g. element `a[1]`, I calculate the memory location by

`element = ((index+1) * 4) + a.Address; // a.Address is the address of a, which is stored in the symbol table, and index is 1 in this case.`

so, the symbol table doesn't store the address of each individual element of 'a', only the address of the symbol and, for each symbol, the next memory address.

I am assuming that the c language uses a stack based implementation for arrays in local scope, such as what I've done. However, how does the C language pass a local array as a parameter to a function, like the following?

`foo(int[] a) {}`

Would a C compiler use the heap or the stack to pass the foregoing array?

Comment: Why `index+1`? Don't you consider `a[0]` to be exactly where `a` points to?

Comment: @Shahbaz: you're right, that calculation was for expository purposes---not my actual code---and isn't correct. so, a is indeed a[0].

Comment: I added some comments on your problem in my answer, in case you are interested.

Comment: The only way, in C, to pass an array on the stack is to wrap it inside a struct and pass the whole struct: `struct whatever { int a[100]; }; foo(struct whatever a);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, arrays decay to pointers when passed as function arguments; `foo(int a[])` is identical to `foo(int * a)`, and only the pointer to the first element "survives" into the function call. There is no way to recover the array size from the pointer within the function call.

Comment: so, in the function---foo(int a[])---we don't know the length of the array. then the c language places the responsibility of knowing that on the programmer?

Comment: You can always wrap the function with a function-like macro that uses `sizeof` to pass the size to the function along with the pointer to the base, but this is probably sufficiently unconventional to make it a bad idea for readability..

Comment: It's not just for function arguments; an array expression decays to a pointer to the array's first element in most contexts (there are three exceptions).  And there's a *separate* rule that says a declared function parameter of array type is "adjusted" to be of pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

C does not pass the array to the function by its contents, but by its address.

Therefore, the argument to the function is in fact a mere `int *` and the value you need to send it is `a.Address`.

---

Let's imagine your hypothetical language though. If the semantics of your language dictates that the array needs to be sent to the function by its contents, then you would need to use **stack** because the parameters of the function reside on the stack.

Note that this brings another complication:

Let's consider this function:

```
int f(int arg1, struct some_struct arg2, float arg3);
```

and let's call some pointer inside this function as the pointer to the stack frame of this function. Let's call it `bp` (base pointer).

So in the function, you would know that `arg1` is at address `bp+8` (for example), arg2 is in address `bp+12` and `arg3` is in address `bp+36` (assuming `sizeof(struct some_struct)` is 20)

Now, if you send arrays by their contents, how about this function?

```
int f(int arg1, int arg2[], float arg3);
```

`arg1` and `arg2` are in the same location, but how about `arg3`? How would you know the location of `arg3`? For that, you need to know the size of `arg2`.

There is a solution to this, though. You could store the size of the array in its first 4 bytes (or 8 bytes if you think the array could be bigger than 4GB). Then, you can safely pass arrays around by their contents (which include their size). In such a case, the address of `a[i]` would be `a.Address+4(or 8)+i*sizeof(*a)`.

There are a few tradeoffs you need to consider:

- Extra memory to keep the size of the array. This used to be an issue at the time C was born, but now perhaps is not an issue anymore.
- Much slower time of function calls because arrays need to be copied.
- More robust code because bound checking can be done at runtime. I personally don't like this though, you get slower execution and your program shouldn't go out of array bounds anyway! It could be a very useful option for debug mode though.
- A better `sizeof` operation for arrays that actually gives the size of the array. This can be useful for functions that just receive an array without its size. `strlen` for example would be O(1).
- Pointers to middle of array would be useless. Think merge sort.
- etc etc

Comment: thanks for the language design suggestions. in particular, i've read a bit more about passing the size of the array with the first 4 bytes; i've read that this is how java arrays are implemented.

Comment: If you are interested in my personal opinion, I think keeping the size of the array in the beginning of it is kind of restrictive. One example of such restriction is that you can't just have a pointer to somewhere inside the array and use that pointer to access the array.

Answer (score 0):

`int []a` is not a valid parameter, you certainly meant `int a[]`.

In C you cannot pass arrays to functions and this form:

```
void foo(int a[]) { ... }
```

is equivalent to this:

```
void foo(int *a) { ... }
```

C always passes by value and usually a copy of pointer `a` is stored on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

(The following pertains to C; if you want to change it for your language, then by all means, go ahead.)

First, realise that you can't pass arrays to functions. You can only pass pointers to functions, so when you see

```
void f(int a[]) { ... }
```

It's actually exactly the same as

```
void f(int* a) { ... }
```

Now that I've said that, I can say that the pointer is passed on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in C are always in the program stack
So even if a variable would be heap and you only pass the pointer address to it, the parameter will still be in stack.
To be in heap you need to allocate memory (malloc).

btw
The best book about C is "The C programming language" from the creator of C Dennis Ritchie who sadly died a few months ago. 
You can take a look here: http://cg.inf.unideb.hu/eng/rtornai/Kernighan_Ritchie_Language_C.pdf  ( I don't know if it's a legal link, just googled it up).
If you are interest in C I'd buy that book, it's worth it.